# ASP MVC 3, UTF-8 HTML charset not showing Polish chars. (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, utf-8, character-encoding

As title says. Story is, I've changed meta mark-up of my _Layout.cshtml page from:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

to

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Effect? No Polish characters on page. Ok, let's revert the change. Effect? No Polish characters on page.

Btw it affects ONLY _Layout.cshtml, all other views show Polish letters properly. Proper letters are replaced by "Ĺ‚" characters.

Any ideas? Thought about changing browser, but it didn't work. Same stuff happens on different computer.

No other changes were made. Tried to revert project to older version from repository, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opened in notebook and saved again wit UTF-8 encoding set. Worked.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I was gonna say that that's probably due to encoding mismatch between the file and specified <meta content> tag.

Comment: Thanks. I open this file with notepad++ and change encoding from "Encode UTF-8 without BOM" to "Encode UTF-8" save this file. Now UTF-8 char set meta tag works good.